# updating an object with seraph or seraph model

Tags: angularjs, node.js, neo4j

i want to update an object in a neo4j database using seraph
this is the code i've used but it add always a new object and don't update the selected one

```
app.put('/contactlist/:name',function (req,res){


db.find({name: req.params.name},function (err,docs){
  db.save({name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, number: req.body.number},'test',function (err,tt){
  res.json(tt);
});
  console.log(docs);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an `id` property.

If you read the seraph readme it states

> save(object, [label,]|[key, value,] callback)
>
> Aliases: node.save
>
> Create or update a node. **If object has an id property, the node with
>   that id is updated.** Otherwise, a new node is created. Returns the
>   newly created/updated node to the callback.